# iPad - Test an HTML5 site on a Win7 PC

Tags: windows, ipad, html

I'm looking to target a website specifically for an iPad but we don't have any Macs in house for testing.  What's the most accurate way to test the site on a PC?  I image I could use the Safari browser and shrink the window down to approximate the iPad screen size but I wonder if there's a better method out there.

Comment: Go to your nearest Apple store and play on one of the demo iPads. That's the only way of properly testing it without buying or borrowing one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you target a website specifically for a **particular device**, buy that **particular device**. This doesn't only apply to iPad.

Two caveats I noticed a lot of websites have for a touch-oriented device like an iPad, iPhone:

1. The mouse-hover event isn't generated. So, the HTML/CSS/Javascript menu structure which works without clicking on a WebKit browser (like Safari) on a mouse-oriented device might stop working completely.
2. The scrolling event (coming from a flick of a finger) is not passed to elements inside a page; instead it just scrolls the entire page. A subelement shown with a scroll bar on a non-touch-oriented device might be shown without the scroll bar at all. So, sometimes you lose the ability to scroll inside a subelement.

There might be other caveats. It's really difficult to imagine all the way a device might behave differently from a mouse-oriented device; so, buy an iPad.

By the way, it's of no use to buy a Mac in this situation: Safari on a Mac still behaves (as far as the mouse/touch events are concerned) rather differently from Safari on an iPad/iPhone.  An iPad can be paired with a Windows PC.

See [this Apple document](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/technotes/tn2010/tn2262/index.html) for a few advices for preparing a web page for the iPad.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just use Safari, as the mobile version uses the same rendering engine (though possibly modified to fit the iPads resources).

It should display the same, if not close.

Comment: That may be true for very basic layout questions, but it is no substitute for the real thing when it comes to interactions, and any iPad specific features any iPad targeted webapp should include.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use online imitation services. 
For example http://app.crossbrowsertesting.com/, or https://saucelabs.com/. They provide lots of imitations environments, for different devices and OS. You can test the site, that is already in the web, or your local files. 
I myself am working currently with app.crossbrowsertesting.com for the first time. It really shows the problem, that the client encountered on his iPad. Also have good notices about these services from experienced developer, a friend of mine.